# Difference between pre ICS and post ICS Holo theme related

Tags: android, themes, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a couple of app that were created with Android 1.6 and after. The problem is when I run these app on recent Android (device or simulator) like ICS, I don't have the Holo theme.

I know i can find a lot of thread on how to specify the theme but when I create a new app now, I have the new theme without any lines of code.

I don't want to have ICS theme on all android version, just ICS theme on ICS, like new holo buttons style on ICS and old grey style for older. Now I just have grey buttons for all versions.

I can create new empty projects and copy all my files into it but there must be a hidden value somewhere to chenge this.

In my manifest I have:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

What can be the difference between old and new created projects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I'm understanding is that you want your app to switch between the legacy (classic) theme and the new Holo theme based on API version.

First, in your `values` (`res/values`) folder make a new xml. Call it `styles.xml`. It should contain these lines:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black"/>
</resources>
```

Then make a new folder in `res` called `values-v11`. In this new folder make another new xml. Also name it `styles.xml` This file should contain these lines:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"/>
</resources>
```

Then in your `AndroidManifest.xml` you `Application` node should contain this line:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Now on devices with Honeycomb or higher you get the Holo theme and for everything else, you get the old classic theme. You can easily experiment with this to suit your needs - this is the general way to switch between themes based on API version.

Comment: I just have checked a recent app that display Holo theme on ICS and i don't have a styles.xml that specify what theme it should use. I don't have a style.xml at all. There must be another option to discover.

Comment: It could be that if you don't specify **any** theme in the `AndroidManifest` it defaults to the devices default, which is `Theme.black` on pre Honeycomb and `Theme.holo` on Honeycomb and up.

Comment: Oh yesss, i had in the manifest->activity tag the line (android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"). I would never think it wil change something else that the title bar.